# How to calculate number of rectangles in rectangular grid?

Tags: math, formula

I want to calculate number of rectangles in a rectangles.It can be done using formula

(x^2+x)(y^2+y)/4

but it also includes perfect squares like 1*1,2*2,3*3 etc.I dont want to include that in my calculations.How can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, you have the number of rectangles with integer coordinates between the points `(0, 0)`, `(x, 0)`, `(x, y)` and `(0, y)`, `x` and `y` being integers too. You now need to remove the perfect squares from this sum.

To compute it, let's evaluate the number of squares `1*1`: there are obviously `x*y` of them. For squares `2*2`, we have `x-1` choices for the x-coordinate and `y-1` for the y-coordinate of the bottom left-hand corner of such a square, due to the width of this square: this results in `(x-1)*(y-1)` squares. Idem, we will have `(x-2)*(y-2)` squares `3*3`, etc.

So for a given `i`, we have `(x - i + 1) * (y - i + 1)` squares `i*i`, and `i` goes from `1` to the minimum of `x` and `y` (of course if `x` is 4 and `y` is 7, we cannot have a square with a side greater than 4).

So if `m = min(x, y)`, we have:

```
Sum_Squares = Sum(i = 1, i = m, (x - i + 1) * (y - i + 1))
            = Sum(j = 0, j = m - 1, (x - i) * (y - i))
            = Sum(j = 0, j = m - 1, x*y - (x+y)*j + j^2)
            = m*x*y - (x+y)*Sum(j = 0, j = m - 1, j) + Sum(j = 0, j = m - 1, j^2)
            = m*x*y - (x+y)*Sum(j = 1, j = m - 1, j) + Sum(j = 1, j = m - 1, j^2)
            = m*x*y - (x+y)*m*(m-1)/2 + (m-1)*m*(2*m-1)/6
```

I get that with an index change (`j = i - 1`) and via the well-known formulas:

```
Sum(i = 1, i = n, j) = n*(n + 1)/2
Sum(i = 1, i = n, j^2) = n*(n + 1)*(2*n + 1)/6
```

You just have to remove this `Sum_Squares` from `(x^2+x)(y^2+y)/4` and you're done !